# Cómo recibo la imagen en ajax y como la mandó a un archivo php

Tags: php, ajax, imagen

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$.ajax({
    "url":"phpfiles/ruta.php",
    "dataType":"json",
    "type":"post",
    "data":{
        anom_select : $("#funo").val(),
        anom_marca : $("#fdos").val(),
        anom_modelo : $("#ftres").val(),
        anom_medidas: $("#fcuatro").val(),
        anomalia_text: $("#fcinco").val()
    }
})
```

Cómo podría con esta petición AJAX y mandar a un archivo PHP.

Comment: con un código que funcione creo

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que quieres enviar una imagen cargada desde un input de un formulario. Para enviar dicho archivo a travez de un Ajax es necesario que utilices la clase **FormData**. Los atributos **cache**, **contentType** y **processData** es necesario que nos pongas a false para que funcione bien la petición:

```
        var formData = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
          url: "upload.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          success: function(data){
              //
          },error:function(){
            //
          },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
        });
```